# As it is referenced in the xpath to a one more view tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy framework and I can not load the other data from my analyzed webpage, it has a tag to see more. Could you tell me what you could do about it, thank you.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from prueba1.items import Prueba1Item
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class PruebaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'prueba1'
    item_count = 0
    allowed_domain = ['http://www.abc.com.py/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.abc.com.py/buscar/?buscar=Santiago+Pe%C3%B1a'
    'http://www.abc.com.py/buscar/?buscar=Santi+Pe%C3%B1a',
    'http://www.abc.com.py/buscar/?buscar=santiago+pe%C3%B1a',
    'http://www.abc.com.py/buscar/?buscar=santi+pe%C3%B1a']

    rules = {


    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(),canonicalize = True, unique = 
    True,restrict_xpaths=('//html/body/div/a[@id="load-more"]'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(),canonicalize = True, unique = 
    True,restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="article"]')),
    callback = 'parse_item', follow=True)
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item=Prueba1Item()

        ml_item['article'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//h1)').extract()
        ml_item['fecha'] = response.xpath('normalize-
        space(//small)').extract()
       ml_item['contenido'] = response.xpath('normalize-
       space(//p[@class="summary"])').extract()
       ml_item['contenido2'] = response.xpath('normalize-
       space(//div[@class="text"])').extract()
       ml_item['url'] = response.xpath('normalize-
       space(//link/@href)').extract()
       ml_item['comentarioFacebook'] = response.xpath('normalize-
       space(//div[@class="_30o4"]/span/span[@class="_5mdd"])').extract()

       self .item_count += 1
       if self.item_count > 50:
           raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield ml_item
```

According to the search results I have more than 4000 results but I can not bring more than 50 with this code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The contents are loaded dynamically using json in this format:

```json
   {
      "titulo": "Tuma se suma a Marito",
      "copete": "El diputado \u00d3scar Tuma oficializ\u00f3 su respaldo a la candidatura de Mario Abdo Ben\u00edtez a la presidencia, ya que sus reportes indicaron que el candidato de Colorado A\u00f1etet\u00e9 tiene mayor intenci\u00f3n de votos. El 100% de su dirigencia se lo pidi\u00f3, dice. ",
      "publicacion": "09-11-2017 08:00",
      "imagen": "2017\/10\/02\/el-diputado-scar-tuma-inscribio-ayer-las-precandidaturas-de-su-movimiento-tu-asuncion-en-la-junta-de-gobierno--200750000000-1634915.jpg",
      "url": "nacionales\/tuma-se-suma-a-marito-1648202.html",
      "autor": "",
      "hits": "3163",
      "comentarios": "1",
      "corte_url": "https:\/\/s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com\/assets.abc.com.py\/2017\/10\/02\/_146_162_1542245.jpg",
      "corte_width": 146,
      "corte_height": 162,
      "autor_nombre": null,
      "autor_url": "http:\/\/www.abc.com.py\/autor\/-.html",
      "total": "4861"
    }
```

Therefore you can get the data in json format directly from the url below without using Xpath or css selector(**try open this url in your browser**): 
http://www.abc.com.py/ajax.php?seccion=busqueda-avanzada&tipo=4&tipoplant=0&buscar=Santiago+Pe%C3%B1a&desde=&hasta=&seccion-noticia=&temas=&begin=0&limit=7&aditional=

I believe it's not difficult to modify the url to get the data you want and put them into your scripts, for example, get 10 items from the second item, just change `begin` to 2 and `limit` to 10:

http://www.abc.com.py/ajax.php?seccion=busqueda-avanzada&tipo=4&tipoplant=0&buscar=Santiago+Pe%C3%B1a&desde=&hasta=&seccion-noticia=&temas=&begin=2&limit=10&aditional=

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution, I am going to prove it

Comment: You are welcome, consider accept the answer if it solved your problem.